# Wkhtmltopdf images not reused after loading other images, results in large pdf size

Tags: html, asp.net, pdf, pdf-generation, wkhtmltopdf

I've noticed some strange behavior with wkhtmltopdf. When reusing the same images, wkhtmltopdf doesn't reuse the images and adds them for a second time to the pdf. This largely increases the pdf size.

---

#### Example #1 - Two different images

```
<img src="https://www.teahub.io/photos/full/183-1832397_new-zealand-sunset-wallpaper-5-mb-image-download.jpg" width="800" />

<img src="https://www.velassaru.com/imagebank/06-spa/pix/Yoga.jpg" width="800" />
```

**Output: 5.2 MB** (this meets the image sizes)

---

#### Example #2 - Two different images, last image gets repeated

```
<img src="https://www.teahub.io/photos/full/183-1832397_new-zealand-sunset-wallpaper-5-mb-image-download.jpg" width="800" />

<img src="https://www.velassaru.com/imagebank/06-spa/pix/Yoga.jpg" width="800" />
<img src="https://www.velassaru.com/imagebank/06-spa/pix/Yoga.jpg" width="800" />
<img src="https://www.velassaru.com/imagebank/06-spa/pix/Yoga.jpg" width="800" />
<img src="https://www.velassaru.com/imagebank/06-spa/pix/Yoga.jpg" width="800" />
<img src="https://www.velassaru.com/imagebank/06-spa/pix/Yoga.jpg" width="800" />
<img src="https://www.velassaru.com/imagebank/06-spa/pix/Yoga.jpg" width="800" />
```

**Output: 5.2 MB** (same as example #1)

---

#### Example #3 - Two different images, each image after each other

```
<img src="https://www.teahub.io/photos/full/183-1832397_new-zealand-sunset-wallpaper-5-mb-image-download.jpg" width="800" />
<img src="https://www.velassaru.com/imagebank/06-spa/pix/Yoga.jpg" width="800" />

<img src="https://www.teahub.io/photos/full/183-1832397_new-zealand-sunset-wallpaper-5-mb-image-download.jpg" width="800" />
<img src="https://www.velassaru.com/imagebank/06-spa/pix/Yoga.jpg" width="800" />

<img src="https://www.teahub.io/photos/full/183-1832397_new-zealand-sunset-wallpaper-5-mb-image-download.jpg" width="800" />
<img src="https://www.velassaru.com/imagebank/06-spa/pix/Yoga.jpg" width="800" />
```

**Output: 7.9 MB** (this increases the pdf size.. but the images are the same)

---

How is this possible? Does wkhtmltopdf not reuse the image when they are the same?

I've tested this also with local files, same issue. The problem occurs when the previous image repeat gets stopped by a new image. But the image that then gets loaded is still the same as the other already loaded/added images.

Comment: This Very much sounds like it should be a bug report in the wkhtmltopdf github repo

Comment: Already did. No response

Answer (score 0):

I experienced the same problem. In my case I had PDF files consist of more than 1000 pages and background image was repetitively rendered in each page by `wkhtmltopdf` and the final PDF file's size reaches nearly hundreds of MBs. (which is inacceptible). I tried various parameters like `--image-dpi`, `--image-quality`, `--lowquality` but none of them worked (only brought a few MBs of size decrease)

The final solution was to use `pdftk` tool (following [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1066537/1715647)) and apply a watermark to each pdf file using its `multibackground` command. By this way, I obtained watermarked PDF files with no significant size increase (only 100 KBs increase of size for each PDF file).